# Is it good practice to pass a specific NSTimeInterval to setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval?

Tags: ios, swift, background-fetch

I'm I obliged to pass either `UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum` or `UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalNever` ?

Or Is it possible to pass a custom interval instead, for example 10 minutes:

`UIApplication.sharedApplication().setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(600.0)`

In my App, I have to download some new updated data while the app is in the background.

Then I'll use the new data to send a local notification to the user.

Answer (score 1):

I looked up apis and found this:

```
func setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(_ minimumBackgroundFetchInterval: NSTimeInterval)
```

And there is a tip for this:

> The minimum number of seconds that must elapse before another
>   background fetch can be initiated. This value is advisory only and
>   does not indicate the exact amount of time expected between fetch
>   operations.

So I think you'd better not depend on that time interval.